# Unable to assign pods to nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I have set up a small Kubernetes cluster on a few old devices. Node 1 is a VM running on my computer, node 2 is an old laptop and node 3 is a Raspberry Pi 3B+.

I'm trying to deploy Octoprint to the RPi using Helm. I'm using the nodeSelector in my values to directly use the hostname but the scheduler fails to assign it to node-03.

I do see a failed scheduling event.

> 0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector. preemption: 0/3 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling, 2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod

Breaking this message down, from what I understand, "1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector" means that only 1 node didn't match the pods node selector. I don't think this should be the case, the node selector should only match with one hostname. "Preemption is not helpful for scheduling" is referring to evicting existing pods to make room (There is only one other pod running).

```
> kubectl get nodes --show-labels
node-01   Ready    control-plane,etcd,master   27d   v1.28.2+k3s1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=node-01,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane=true,node-role.kubernetes.io/etcd=true,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=true
node-02   Ready    <none>                      27d   v1.28.2+k3s1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=node-02,kubernetes.io/os=linux
node-03   Ready    <none>                      27d   v1.28.2+k3s1   3dprinter=Prusai3MK3Sp,beta.kubernetes.io/arch=arm64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/arch=arm64,kubernetes.io/hostname=node-03,kubernetes.io/os=linux,rpi=RPi3b,webcam=true
```

```
> kubectl describe helmreleases octoprint
Name:         octoprint
Namespace:    default
Labels:       kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/name=cluster-apps-octoprint
              kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/namespace=flux-system
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
Kind:         HelmRelease
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2023-11-08T18:37:58Z
  Finalizers:
    finalizers.fluxcd.io
  Generation:        37
  Resource Version:  14108621
  UID:               5b283e04-c4c9-40b3-9eb9-77e8061bb5e2
Spec:
  Chart:
    Spec:
      Chart:               octoprint
      Reconcile Strategy:  ChartVersion
      Source Ref:
        Kind:       HelmRepository
        Name:       k8s-at-home-charts
        Namespace:  flux-system
      Version:      6.4.2
  Install:
    Create Namespace:  true
    Remediation:
      Retries:  3
  Interval:     5m
  Upgrade:
    Remediation:
      Retries:  4
  Values:
    Env:
      OCTOPRINT_PORT:  5000
      TZ:              America/Los_Angeles
    Image:
      Pull Policy:  IfNotPresent
      Repository:   octoprint/octoprint
      Tag:          1.9.3
    Ingress:
      Main:
        Annotations:
          hajimari.io/icon:  mdi:printer-3d
        Enabled:             true
        Hosts:
          Host:  octoprint.hostname.com
          Paths:
            Path:            /
            Path Type:       Prefix
        Ingress Class Name:  internal
        Tls:
          Hosts:
            octoprint.hostname.com
    Node Selector:
      kubernetes.io/hostname:  node-03
    Persistence:
      Data:
        Enabled:         true
        Existing Claim:  octoprint-data
        Mount Path:      /octoprint
      Printer:
        Enabled:     true
        Host Path:   /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Prusa_Research__prusa3d.com__Original_Prusa_i3_MK3_CZPX0321X004XK45917-if00
        Mount Path:  /dev/ttyUSB0
        Type:        hostPath
    Security Context:
      Privileged:  true
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2023-11-30T17:49:38Z
    Message:               upgrade retries exhausted
    Reason:                UpgradeFailed
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
    Last Transition Time:  2023-11-30T17:49:30Z
    Message:               Helm upgrade failed: context deadline exceeded

Last Helm logs:

Looks like there are no changes for Ingress "octoprint"
waiting for release octoprint resources (created: 0 updated: 3  deleted: 0)
beginning wait for 3 resources with timeout of 5m0s
Deployment is not ready: default/octoprint. 0 out of 1 expected pods are ready
warning: Upgrade "octoprint" failed: context deadline exceeded
    Reason:                        UpgradeFailed
    Status:                        False
    Type:                          Released
    Last Transition Time:          2023-11-30T18:26:28Z
    Message:                       Helm rollback succeeded
    Reason:                        RollbackSucceeded
    Status:                        True
    Type:                          Remediated
  Failures:                        97
  Helm Chart:                      flux-system/default-octoprint
  Last Applied Revision:           6.4.2
  Last Attempted Revision:         6.4.2
  Last Attempted Values Checksum:  9dfbce303086173def108a385f75713496aaf4a4
  Last Release Revision:           129
  Observed Generation:             37
  Upgrade Failures:                5
Events:
  Type     Reason  Age                    From             Message
  ----     ------  ----                   ----             -------
  Warning  error   9m34s (x100 over 23h)  helm-controller  reconciliation failed: upgrade retries exhausted
```

```
> kubectl describe node node-03             
Name:               node-03
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             3dprinter=Prusai3MK3Sp
                    beta.kubernetes.io/arch=arm64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/arch=arm64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=node-03
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    rpi=RPi3b
                    webcam=true
Annotations:        k3s.io/node-args:
                      ["agent","--node-ip","192.168.1.196","--server","https://192.168.1.197:6443","--token-file","/etc/rancher/k3s/cluster-token","--config","/...
                    k3s.io/node-config-hash: U6IKRFV6ICKEL6S64TM5DKYJM42METEUKUXKMBUT7E766KIKQ2CA====
                    k3s.io/node-env: {"K3S_DATA_DIR":"/var/lib/rancher/k3s/data/216186d17d098d26f7da0d12e7228379cc3ea6c5ec5b709291ff30dcb4282624"}
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Fri, 03 Nov 2023 01:49:16 +0000
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  node-03
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Thu, 30 Nov 2023 18:05:32 +0000
Conditions:
  Type                 Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----                 ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  NetworkUnavailable   False   Fri, 03 Nov 2023 01:51:26 +0000   Fri, 03 Nov 2023 01:51:26 +0000   CiliumIsUp                   Cilium is running on this node
  MemoryPressure       False   Thu, 30 Nov 2023 18:05:12 +0000   Thu, 30 Nov 2023 17:53:17 +0000   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure         False   Thu, 30 Nov 2023 18:05:12 +0000   Thu, 30 Nov 2023 17:53:17 +0000   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure          False   Thu, 30 Nov 2023 18:05:12 +0000   Thu, 30 Nov 2023 17:53:17 +0000   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready                True    Thu, 30 Nov 2023 18:05:12 +0000   Thu, 30 Nov 2023 17:53:17 +0000   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status. AppArmor enabled
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  *.*.*.*
  Hostname:    node-03
Capacity:
  cpu:                4
  ephemeral-storage:  30131856Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  hugepages-32Mi:     0
  hugepages-64Ki:     0
  memory:             924384Ki
  pods:               110
Allocatable:
  cpu:                4
  ephemeral-storage:  29312269494
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  hugepages-32Mi:     0
  hugepages-64Ki:     0
  memory:             924384Ki
  pods:               110
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 e316535f13bf40b88fb24cb9f54c8724
  System UUID:                e316535f13bf40b88fb24cb9f54c8724
  Boot ID:                    c262d685-f7cf-4f82-a8d2-feac53f7db6b
  Kernel Version:             6.1.0-9-arm64
  OS Image:                   Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               arm64
  Container Runtime Version:  containerd://1.7.6-k3s1
  Kubelet Version:            v1.28.2+k3s1
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.28.2+k3s1
PodCIDR:                      10.42.2.0/24
PodCIDRs:                     10.42.2.0/24
Non-terminated Pods:          (1 in total)
  Namespace                   Name            CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----            ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  kube-system                 cilium-hb2qb    100m (2%)     0 (0%)      100Mi (11%)      0 (0%)         6d
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests     Limits
  --------           --------     ------
  cpu                100m (2%)    0 (0%)
  memory             100Mi (11%)  0 (0%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)       0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)       0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)       0 (0%)
  hugepages-32Mi     0 (0%)       0 (0%)
  hugepages-64Ki     0 (0%)       0 (0%)
Events:
  Type     Reason                   Age                From             Message
  ----     ------                   ----               ----             -------
```

How can I find the scheduler logs to find how why the pod is not being assigned to the node I want?

**Edit**: Changed values -> `helm get values octoprint` -> `kubectl describe helmreleases octoprint`

Comment: Can you use `helm get values RELEASE_NAME` command so I'll be able to see the actual values on your helm deployment?

Comment: And if you add double quotes like "node-03"

Comment: @Hackerman, just tried the double quotes. Didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @SeanO'Rourke I don't see node selector in provided values. Could you please add `kubectl describe pod pod-name`, so we can see what actually happens.

Comment: @DmytroSirant ah, thanks. Deployment failed so it rolled back. Changed to describe the Helm Release.